# Adplus.config - <AllExceptions> vs <Exception Code="*">

Tags: windbg, adplus

I'm new to WinDbg and ADPlus, and have a pretty basic question. The documentation in ADPlus.doc talks about an `<AllExceptions>` section. But I have seen example adplus.config files that use `<Exception Code="*">`.

What is the difference between these two? Do they do the same thing? Does it matter which one I use?

Answer (score 1):

When using Exception Code you can specify different action for different exceptions.
This is the most common usage in a debug situation.

The AllExceptions is handy if you want to have the same action for all types of exception. However the `Log`  is probably the only sensible action here.

I have never tried to mix both in the same config file !

Comment: If I use `<Exception Code="*">` -- note the wildcard -- is it the same as if I were to put an `<AllExceptions>` block in the config file?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t know, but logically it should be the same.